# Shift buffer mechanism and bitwidth discrepancy

Tags: verilog, fpga

For https://github.com/KastnerRG/riffa/blob/master/fpga/riffa_hdl/fifo_packer_128.v#L113 , is it sensible to have **224 bits** for signal '*rPackedData*' ?

Besides, do anyone have any idea regarding the following code segment which **OR together** the shifted-in data ? Should it not be **AND** instead ?

```
_rPackedData = ((rPackedData>>(32*{rPackedCount[2], 2'd0})) | (rDataMasked<<(32*rPackedCount[1:0])));
```

Answer (score 1):

> any idea regarding the following code segment which OR together the shifted-in data ? Should it not be AND instead ?

The left half of that expression shifts stored data **OUT**, zeroing some higher bits. The right half shifts **IN** new data, placing it at required position at higher portion of the buffer, and padding lower bits with zero. In order to get updated content of the buffer you need to **OR** both halves of the expression. If you will try to **AND** it, you'll get completely zeroed buffer, since valid data from the left and right halves of expression does not overlap.

Comment: it seems that if 'rPackedCount' is equal to 3 , then the shifted-in data will need occupy 224 bits since 3*32+128 = 224

In this case, this is taking up a lot of hardware logic. Do you guys have any clever tricks to emulate the same shift buffer mechanism without using this much of hardware logic ?

Comment: @kevin, the only 'trick' is to spend more clock ticks to do the same job with smaller hw :)

Comment: What do you have in mind regarding https://github.com/KastnerRG/riffa/blob/master/fpga/riffa_hdl/fifo_packer_128.v#L40 ?

> Assumes the FIFO always has room to accommodate the data.

Comment: @kevin that line means that consumer fifo does not implement any kind of backpressure (or entire datapath' design doesn't require it) so this packer just spits out accumulated 128-bit word, regardless of fifo's current state.